# Getting error on distance calculation with google map API -

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, distance

I am trying to create a taxi fare calculator based on UK with google map API. I'm new to google map area and I've done the project with some javascript from online.

Everything alright but some places like "Heathrow Terminal 2, UK" doesn't allow to get the result. (Type "terminal 2" autocomplete will get).

Please help me to correct this or suggest me If there any other better ways to do it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue **in the question itself** (not just a link to an external site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google does not keep record or does not show records related to sensitive places for security reasons, for example for this address **Heathrow Terminal 2, Hounslow, United Kingdom** google API returns **ZERO_RESULTS**.

You have asked for the working code, but these is just the explanation of such behavior of Google API.